# I can't connect to mysql with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js, digital-ocean

I can't connect to mysql with sequelize, 
I can't establish a connection with the mysql server (the mysql version is 8).

gives me this error that I can't solve even looking on the internet.
I'm using a mysql database provided by digitalocean

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const fs = require('fs')


const sequelize = new Sequelize('defaultdb','user','pass',
{
    dialect : 'mysql',
    port : '25060',
    host: 'db-mysql-fra1-insquare-do-user-6497882-0.db.ondigitalocean.com',
    dialectOptions: {
        ca   : 'fs.readFileSync("ca-certificate.crt").toString()'
    }

}
);


module.exports = sequelize;
```

```
Connession al DB Error: { SequelizeConnectionError: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Promise.tap.then.catch.err (/root/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:133:19)
    at tryCatcher (/root/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/root/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/root/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/root/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/root/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:695:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/root/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/root/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/root/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/root/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)
```

Comment: I am also getting the same error. So any luck for you? Did you resolved it?